# Can't see simple form in Rails 3 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get to work **simple-private-messages** gem. I done everything like in sample.

But now when I try to access **localhost:3000/users/1/messages/**

I can't see anything. There is nothing. i have like this:

```
   <% form_tag delete_selected_user_messages_path(@user, :method => :post) do %>
        <% if params[:mailbox] == "sent" %>
                <%= render :partial => "sent" %>
        <% else %>
                <%= render :partial => "inbox" %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But when I remove if statement.

```
  <%= render :partial => "sent" %>
  <%= render :partial => "inbox" %>
```

Then I can see everything. Why It is messing with params[:mailbox] ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<% form_tag delete_selected_user_messages_path(@user, :method => :post) do %>
```

Do:

```
<%= form_tag delete_selected_user_messages_path(@user, :method => :post) do %>
```